# C function pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am learning C from "C by K&R". I was going through Function pointers section.There was an example to sort an array of strings using function pointers and void pointers.(to be specific,on page 100). I have a fair understanding of function pointers and void pointers.

The example given there calls

```
qsort((void**) lineptr, 0, nlines-1,(int (*)(void*,void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp));
```

And it seemlessly uses void ptr,like as below to compare and swap.

I understand that it takes array of pointer and each element by itself is a void pointer to the string. How is it possible to compare,swap a void ptr with another.

```
void sort(void *v[],int i,int j)
{
    id *temp;
    temp = v[i]; 
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;  
}
```

Can anyone explain the concept behind this.

Comment: When you swap two pointers, you do not change the data it points to in any way.

Comment: ofcourse you cant dereference void * but here  you are just changing what the pointers point to .

Comment: Does your code actually work?

Comment: I wonder why so many upvotes?

Comment: be careful when copying,  this line: `id *temp;` seems to be missing the leading: `vo`

Answer (score 2):

> How is it possible to compare, swap a `void ptr` with another?

- Compare: comparing a `void ptr` with each other is meaningless, as their values are addresses.
- Swap: A pointer is a variable holding an address. By changing a pointer's value you change the address it points to. Data itself is not even considered here.

---

Note: void pointers does not interpret the data they are pointing to. That is why you need explicit type conversion when you dereference them, such that there is a correspondence between the data they are pointing to and the variable this data is assign to.

Comment: Please explain "*meaningless*".

Comment: in the context of the question, if you compare the value of the void ptr what meaningfull information would it give you?

Comment: Whether or not both pointers point to the same address? You mean that sorting by address doesn't have any meaning because the order will be somwhat arbitrary, right?

Comment: Fair enough, I'm referring mostly in terms of the data they are pointing to. You could also check relative position in memory, estimate size etc, but this doesn't help in the sorting, that's why I use the word "meaningless".

Comment: Exactly, the address, i.e the pointer value,  doesn't correspond to the value of the variable that needs to be sorted.

Comment: Comparing addresses is meaningful as addresses have a partial order according to the C standard (addresses are absolutely ordered within an object but behaviour is unspecified outside).

Comment: @FUZxxl Within an array, for example, the addresses will be consecutive. That is what you say, right? If so, I agree. :)

Comment: @simplicisveritatis Yeah, almost. I just said that addresses are well-ordered within an array, but they may not be consecutive. (Imagine a system that doesn't use the least-significant bit so all addresses are even).

Comment: @iharob Not quite, what I say is that `void*` is a low level language tool that deals with addresses, without any concern about high-level data structures.

Comment: I love the way how someone is reversing his vote few times now! The force is strong with you brother. :) P.S. considering that I am 1 point away from 2000p milestone.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that pointers are just variables that store a memory address. If there's not any conflict between types I can't see why this shouldn't be possible!
The only difference between a `void` ptr and another is that you must pay attention only during the dereference (you need a cast to complete it)
For example:

```
void *ptr;
int m, n;
ptr = &n;
m = *((int *) ptr);
```

Anyway, ignoring this particular, you can work with `void` pointer normally.. You can, as your code shows, for example swap them just as they were `int` or other types variables

Answer (score 0):

The function pointer required by `qsort()` has the following type

```
int (*compar)(const void *, const void *);
```

it means, that you can pass pointers of any type to this function since in [c](/questions/tagged/c) `void *` is converted to any poitner type without a cast.

Inside a comparision funcion, you MUST "*cast*"<sup>1</sup> the `void *` poitners in order to be able to dereference them. Because a `void *` pointer cannot be dereferenced.

Swaping pointers is the correct way to sort an array of poitners, just like swaping integers would be the way to sort an array of integers. The other way, with an array of *strings* for example, would be to copy the string to a temporary buffer and perform a swap in terms of copying the data, and I think there is no need to explain why this is bad.

---

<sup>1</sup>
<sub>When I say cast I don't mean that you need to "*cast*", just convert to the appropriate poitner type. For example:</sub>

```
int compare_integers(const void *const x, const void *const y)
{
    int *X;
    int *Y;

    X = x;
    Y = y;

    return (*X - *Y);
}
```

although it's of course possible to write `return (*((int *) x) - *((int *) y))`.

Answer (score 0):

In this type of situation, it's often helpful to `typedef` to gain a better understanding. For illustration purposes, you could do

```
typedef void* address;   //to emphasize that a variable of type void* stores an address
```

Now your swap function looks less daunting,

```
void swap(address v[],int i,int j)  //takes an array of addresses v
{
    address temp;
    temp = v[i]; 
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;  
}
```

A `void *`, however, contains no information regarding the type of object it points to. So before dereferencing it, you need to cast it to the right type, which is what `strcmp` and `numcmp` do, e.g.,

```
int strcmp(address a1, address a2) {  //assumes a1 and a2 store addresses of strings
    char *s1  = a1;
    char *s2 = a2;
    //s1 and s2 can be dereferenced and the strings they point to can be compared
}
```

Comment: @All : Thanks a lot. I missed that they are address and not the data that are swapped. Was not having access to internet,hence the delay..